# Polygons disappear when filtering WDPA marine polygons in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a collection of countries that I filter from WDPA to give me the protected area polygons for those countries. The problem arises however when I want to filter the polygons to only show me terrestrial polygons. This is done by specifying the "MARINE"-band as 0 which then should only show the polygons with this designation. When I do this however the map doesn't display anything, and I'm not quite sure why.

Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5c99655210f64d7126bd3d555f6f085d

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons');


var countries = ee.List(['MEX', 'GTM', 'NIC', 'CRI', 'PAN', 'COL', 'VEN', 'SUR', 'ECU', 'PER', 'BRA', 'BOL', 'PRY', 'URY', 'ARG', 'SLE', 'LBR', 'CIV', 'GHA', 'TGO', 'BEN', 'NGA', 'CMR', 'GNQ', 'GAB', 'COD', 'COG', 'RWA', 'UGA', 'KEN', 'TZA', 'MOZ', 'MWI', 'AGO', 'ZWE', 'ZMB', 'BWA', 'ZAF', 'MDG', 'THA', 'IND', 'MMR', 'LAO', 'VNM', 'KHM', 'MYS', 'IDN', 'PHL', 'PNG', 'TLS']);

var selected = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.inList('PARENT_ISO', countries));


var protected_terrestrial = selected.filter(ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.eq('MARINE', 0),
  ee.Filter.neq('STATUS', 'proposed')));

Map.addLayer(protected_terrestrial, {}, 'Protected Areas');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the MARINE column is of type string, It's missing the brackets around the 0, i.e. '0' not 0.